# Firebase Realtime database doesn't add data but Firebase Authentication and Firestore work perfectly

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

There is a question similar to this but it has been stalled. so, I've put up this one.

what I have done is created a flutter app in android studio. I can successfully login but can't update the database.

Here's my code Firebase initialization

```
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

DatabaseReference userRef =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users");
```

The code to authenticate and write to the database

```
     final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  void registerNewUser(BuildContext context) async {
    final User firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: emailTextEditingController.text,
                password: passwordTextEditingController.text)
            .catchError((errMsg) {
      displayToastMessage("Error: " + errMsg.toString(), context);
    }))
        .user;

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      //save user to database

      Map userDataMap = {
        "name": nameTextEditingController.text.trim(),
        "email": emailTextEditingController.text.trim(),
        "phone": phoneTextEditingController.text.trim(),
      };

      userRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).set(userDataMap);
      displayToastMessage(
          "Congratulation, your account has been created", context);
    }
```

The firebase rule

```
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

At this point the user is authenticated, however, in the real-time database, no values are being updated? As i debug it reaches the point

```
Map userDataMap = {
```

and completely skips `"name": nameTextEditingController.text.trim(), "email": emailTextEditingController.text.trim(), "phone": phoneTextEditingController.text.trim(),}` The debugger console is pretty normal, I don't get any errors. Is there any way I can debug this more extensively? or what am I missing?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI6mY.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD77W.jpg)

Comment: it works when you replace the new ```google-service.json```

Comment: I have repleced a new google-service.json and still don't work.. @GaneshMB

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue with my real time database.
The way I fixed it was to pass my initialized firebase app and rtdb url like so :

```
FirebaseDatabase _database =
        FirebaseDatabase(app: firebaseApp, databaseURL: url);
```

and then used this instance to update the real time db

```
    DatabaseReference _ref = _database.reference();
    _ref.child("Movies").push().child("MovieTitle").push().set("new movie");
```

this was the only way I managed to get it working

Comment: Where do you get firebaseApp and url please?

Comment: for firebaseApp you just need to put this line :
`await Firebase.initializeApp();` inside a variable to use it later 
and the URL is just the address of your local emulator or the address in your firebase console

Answer (score 0):

i'm taking the same flutter course and it happened to me too,
try `flutter clean`. it worked for me.